# Get all files using FTP via Unix Terminal

Tags: unix, ftp, terminal, mget

Using the FTP command in the Unix terminal I want to download all files / folders from my FTP server.

When I use this command:

```
ftp> mget *
```

I get lots of these errors:

```
ftp: Unable to determine real path of `subdomains': No such file or directory
Skipping non-relative filename `subdomains/dev'
```

Does anyone know how I can get all files and maintain the directory structure without getting the errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wget can mirror ftp sites as well.  Here is an example on how to mirror [Project Gutenberg Europe](http://pge.rastko.net/howto/mirror-howto).

```
wget --mirror --no-host-directories --passive-ftp --no-parent --cut-dirs=4 \
     --output-file=/tmp/wget-gutenberg.log ftp://ftp.ibiblio.org/pub/docs/books/gutenberg
```

Comment: Excellent, this is even better than the ftp command. +1